# What is this type of sentence called?

Tags: sentence-construction, terminology

- How are you feeling today?
- **Bad**

The second sentence, does it have a name, is it a one-word response?

Comment: I fixed a missing word in the question.

Comment: I'd call it a [minor sentence](http://www.davidcrystal.com/?id=3002).

Comment: "Bad" is a radically elliptical version of "I'm feeling bad". I wouldn't call it a clause, but just a phrase.

Comment: @BillJ But is it a phrase, is it actually a sentence?

Comment: I've edited the tag to indicate that your quest is for jargon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already answered, the correct English term for a complete sentence composed of just one word is a ***sentence word***.

But there are other more *creative* ways you could describe such a statement.

"***Monosyllabic***" describes both a single syllable statement *and* can be used to describe a person who speaks in such a way.

In novels, verbs such as "grunted" may be used to describe the speech someone who spoke in single syllable utterances; for example:

> "How are you feeling", asked Sue.
>   "Bad", grunted Bob.

Answer (score 1):

It's called [**a sentence word**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_word) or **a one-word sentence**:

> A sentence word (also called a one-word sentence) is a single word that forms a full sentence.

Answer (score 1):

A [sentence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sentence) *can* be defined as:

> *a word, clause, or phrase or a group of clauses or phrases forming a syntactic unit which expresses an assertion, a question, a command, a wish, an exclamation, or the performance of an action, that in writing usually begins with a capital letter and concludes with appropriate end punctuation, and that in speaking is distinguished by characteristic patterns of stress, pitch, and pauses*

However, it's more common for it to be thought of in the [following way](https://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-sentence.php):

> In grammar, a sentence is the basic grammatical unit. It contains a group of words and expresses a complete thought.
>
> A sentence consists of a subject and a predicate. For example in the sentence "*Bill writes good poems*" *Bill* is the subject of the sentence and *writes good poems* is the predicate.

The one-word sentence *No* seemingly contains none of those things.

However, those things are both implied by and inferred from the context of the sentence that came before:

> "How are you feeling today?"
>   "(I'm feeling) **Bad** (today)."

In this case, *No* is known as an [*elliptical sentence*](http://www.freeworldu.org/static/grammar/ellipticalsentences.aspx), where one or more words have been omitted yet are assumed to exist in context. (Omitting all but a single word is an extreme form of elliptical construction.)